# REST POST to WCF Service

Tags: rest, wcf, post

I'm trying to post to WCF service. I get this error 
"You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse."

Code:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string postData = "patron=WTM";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8733/FileShareWebServices/UploadFile");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new  StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to move the GetResponse after closing the stream (move it after the using statement for StreamReader)

Comment: @Sparrow - that won't work and will most likely cause OP's code to fail to compile.  The call to `GetResponse` is used to create the `StreamReader` in the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code doesn't write anything to the request stream which is most likely the cause of the error.  Once you get the request stream you should write to it the contents and the length, like this:

```
using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream)
{
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

The complete code would look like this:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string postData = "patron=WTM";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8733/FileShareWebServices/UploadFile");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
//httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Code to write data to the stream
using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream)
{
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new  StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I keep this error " the remote server returned an error (404) Not Found

Comment: @user1836442 - Sounds like you have an issue with the service or the endpoint.